# How to place a multi-line single string JSON in POSTMAN?

Tags: json, post, postman

Here is what I am using in Python 3:

```
    payload={"query": """query 
       {
          organization(login: "MY-ORG-ID") {
             samlIdentityProvider {
                externalIdentities(first: 10) {
                   edges {
                      node {
                         user {login}
                         samlIdentity {nameId}
                         scimIdentity {username}
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }"""
    }

URL     = 'https://api.github.com/graphql'
HEADERS = {'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v4.idl', 'authorization': 'bearer MY-GITHUB-TOKEN'}
response = requests.post(url=URL, json=payload, headers=HEADERS)
```

It just works fine.

However, I am trying to use this query in POSTMAN tool but have no clue how to do this. I tried to remove 3-double quotes `""" """`, I get `Unexpected 'q'` error. When I use double quotes instead of 3-double quotes and `login: \"MY-ORG-ID\"`, I get `"message": "Problems parsing JSON"` error.

There's no problem with headers and URL. I just gave them here for completeness.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're trying to enter the query into body of your post request in the postman app, a quick workaround to achieve multiple lines is to use a placeholder in the form of an environment variable in your body and enter the query in your pre-request script:

In your body:

```
{
"query":{{query}}
}
```

In your pre-request script:

```
pm.environment.set("query", JSON.stringify(
    `
    query {
       organization(login: "MY-ORG-ID") {
          samlIdentityProvider {
             externalIdentities(first: 10) {
                edges {
                   node {
                      user {login}
                      samlIdentity {nameId}
                      scimIdentity {username}
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
    `
));
```

Note that ` in the above code is a backtick, not a single quote!

It's not the best solution ever, but the only one that worked for me so far in Postman to avoid entering more complex queries/mutations in a single line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's good because it works.  It sucks because it's necessary.  Why doesn't Postman just support this?  I mean converting newlines to '\n' implicitly seems kind of obvious doesn't it?

Comment: I got a pm not defined error in postman. Ineed to store a graphql call using postman

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify()` because the content of `query` is not JSON. It is a GraphQL query descriptor. You can simply do `pm.environment.set("query", \`the multiline query descriptor\`)`

Comment: @Steztric, `JSON.stringify` transforms the string to add the newlines, so it is necessary. Alternatively, instead of `JSON.stringify(\`<raw_query>\`)`, you could use the following: `\`"<raw_query>"\`.replaceAll('\n', '\\n')`

Answer (score 3):

Postman has a "graphql" type of request body. It means you can write your query without quotes (see screenshot attached). Also, it is useful when you are assigning variables to query/mutation.

P.S. you might need to update your postman to get a "graphql" type of body payload.

[image: screenshot from Postman UI with "graphql" radio button]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't, therefore you need to turn your multiline string into a single string.

Quickest way to do this is to paste it in a web browser search bar for a format change, then copy and paste from the web browser search bar back into postman.

Comment: Hi @lobi - Thanks for looking into this. ray's solution worked. I haven't gotten a chance to try DennisS1981's solution after that. It looks like your one give's the same single string as ray advised. However, I liked the formatting trick by pasting it in a browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Triple quotes in Python denote a multi-line string right? So try double quotes, and `login: \"MY-ORG-ID\"` and placing the entire query in a single line?

```
 {
   "query":"query{organization(login: \"MY-ORG-ID\") {samlIdentityProvider {externalIdentities(first: 10) {edges {node {user {login}samlIdentity {nameId}scimIdentity {username}}}}}}}"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked when put all those lines in to one. Is there any way to use multi-line?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. You could try adding \n, but then those characters would also be sent in the query.